# Actionscript flash.filesystem

Tags: actionscript-3, load, mp3

I made an mp3 player that populates a list with filenames from an xml file but I want to be able to display the contents of a folder in a list. basically populate the list from a directory insread of from the xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash doesn't allow you to access the local file system in that way. You should look into AIR, as it allows you to do this type of thing. Since AIR is also AS3 based, you won't need to change much code at all, if any. You'll just need to implement the local storage access part.

Comment: I'm continuing to look into AIR, although most resources I've come across are geared towards Flash Builder.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this via **FlashVars** if you wanted to parse a list of files to flash using `scandir()` in PHP. Otherwise, like said, you'll have to use AIR.

The PHP is quite easy anyways; I'd try something similar to this (note this is a really rough example):

Page:

```
<?php
    $arr = scandir("your_directory");
    $joined = implode('#', $arr);

    echo '
    <object width="x" height="y">
        <param name="flashvars" value="files=' . $joined . '" />
        <embed src="media.swf?files=' . $joined . '" width="x" height="y" />
    </object>';
?>
```

AS3:

```
var vars:Object = root.loaderInfo.parameters;
var files:Array = vars.files.split("#");

var i:String;
for each(i in files)
{
    doStuffWith(i);
}

function doStuffWith(file:String):void
{
    // load file etc
}
```

Comment: I guess I assumed that he was looking for a local solution. If this is a server based situation, php will work.

Comment: Yeah; this idea is assuming a server running PHP is an available resource.

Comment: Actually I am doing this locally. I've read conflicting things. Some people say only AIR can do it, others have said Flash can but the user has to allow or perform an action such as a button click to allow the flash swf to access the local fle system where as AIR can do it automatically.

Comment: It's not doable via flash on it's own, that is one of the major reasons that Adobe introduced AIR - direct access to the local file system. You can spend time developing a workaround solution, or you can use the solution - AIR. But it does truly depend on what your goal is with your application. Choosing the right tool for a situation, can save you time and add flexibility.